# Resize column that is part of PK. Find out column length

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to resize two varchar columns - one is part of the PK, the other is under a UNIQUE constraint.
A simple resize* does not work because of the CONSTRAINTs. So I figured I will have to drop the constraints, alter the table, and add the constraints again afterwards. Or is there an easier solution?

If not, I would sleep better if this was only done if the columns do not already have the correct size. How can I find out which maximum length a varchar column supports?

EDIT:
*I tried to use `ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN name VARCHAR(50)` to change the size supported to 50 chars instead of 30, which was a bit short. This operation fails with an error message stating that `name` is a column under UNIQUE constraint `UQ_users`.

Comment: Rather than using SSMS, its better to modify it using query. like this - `ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype`. I think this is what you wants to do right ?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana This is what I want to do, but it fails. I am not playing the SSMS point&click adventure, I use the "new query" button.

Comment: I think in your case you need to drop constraint temporary and alter your column. See and test thoroughly in adventureDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you just about any schema info you need for an entire database. You can pick it apart as needed.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.sysobjects.name AS tblName, dbo.syscolumns.name AS fldName, dbo.systypes.name AS Type, sys.extended_properties.[value] AS Descript, dbo.syscolumns.xprec, dbo.syscolumns.xscale, dbo.syscolumns.length, PK.cnt AS PrmryKey, FK.cnt AS FrnKey, dbo.syscolumns.isnullable, dbo.syscomments.text AS DefaultVal 
FROM dbo.sysobjects 
    INNER JOIN dbo.syscolumns 
        ON dbo.sysobjects.id = dbo.syscolumns.id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.systypes 
        ON dbo.syscolumns.xtype = dbo.systypes.xusertype 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.syscomments 
        ON dbo.syscolumns.cdefault = dbo.syscomments.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties 
        ON dbo.syscolumns.id = sys.extended_properties.major_id 
            AND dbo.syscolumns.colid = sys.extended_properties.minor_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT 1 as CNT, ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id 
            FROM sys.indexes AS i 
                INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic 
                    ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID 
                        AND i.index_id = ic.index_id 
            WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1 ) PK 
        on dbo.syscolumns.id = PK.object_id 
            AND dbo.syscolumns.colid = PK.column_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT fkeyid, fkey, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
            FROM sysforeignkeys 
            GROUP BY fkeyid, fkey) FK 
        ON dbo.syscolumns.id = FK.fkeyid 
            AND dbo.syscolumns.colid = FK.fkey  
WHERE  (dbo.sysobjects.xtype = 'U' OR dbo.sysobjects.xtype = 'V')
    AND (dbo.sysobjects.name <> N'dtproperties') 
    AND (dbo.sysobjects.name <> N'sysconstraints') 
    AND (dbo.sysobjects.name <> N'syssegments') 
--ORDER BY dbo.sysobjects.name, dbo.syscolumns.name
```

Comment: You should update your snippet to use the current views. sysobjects is for backwards compatibility for sql 2000. sys.objects, sys.columns etc.

Comment: But this works in most versions and the OP did not specify a version.

Comment: Agreed. Wasn't being critical. Just suggesting you should update your code snippet. Supporting 2k is not really very important any more as the product has long been out of support.